# Javascript Regex equivalent to PHP Regex

Tags: javascript, php, regex

I am finding words to highlight words with below regex in php

```
/(?<!\\w)".$word."(?!\\w)/
```

I want exact output of this regex using in javascript using regex.

Can anyone suggest above regex's javascript regex?

I want to search for the starting index - ending index of the word matched from the implemented JS regex.

Comment: To *highlight* means you replace the matches. In JS, you need to use a capturing group instead of the lookbehind and insert the contents back to the result with a backreference.

Comment: I need start Index and end index based on above regex's javascript implementation.From above regex the words are coming from server side which need to be highlighted on client side and i also need to save their start index and end index.

Comment: Good. So, where are you stuck? What have you tried to do about the pattern and code?

Comment: I am not able to find out the exact output of this regex from my javascript regex : var regex = new RegExp('(?!<!\\w)' + word + '(?!\\w)');

Comment: what changes i need to make in above regex?

Comment: *In JS, you need to use a capturing group instead of the lookbehind and insert the contents back to the result with a backreference.* JS regex does not support lookbehinds. `'(?!<!\\w)'` -> `'(^|\\W)'`

Comment: So what will be the JS regex of the above php regex as i does not know how capturing group works in Javascript?

Comment: Capturing groups work the same as in PHP.

Answer (score 3):

You can match words using the `\b` (word boundary) token, [like this](http://jsbin.com/ciciqetepa/edit?js,console).

```js
var text = 'I want to match .word. all words that have .word. in them.';
var word = '.word.';
var regex = new RegExp('(' + escapeRegExp(word) + ')');

console.log(text.match(regex));

function escapeRegExp(str) {
  return str.replace(/[\-\[\]\/\{\}\(\)\*\+\?\.\\\^\$\|]/g, "\\$&");
}
```

Edit: Updated due to comments.

Comment: This is of no use: 1) OP needs to build the pattern dynamically, 2) word boundaries won't work if `.word.` is passed.

Comment: exactly..also this will create problems to find word with special characters.

Comment: Now, the whole word check is not performed, and there is no need in the outer parentheses.

Comment: this won't work if i am searching for the word '.wor' then it is returning the match which is in between the .word. in the string

Comment: @BhaveshTilvani This is exactly what your RegExp `/(?<!\\w)".$word."(?!\\w)/` does. Could you clarify more in your original question, if this is not what you need?

Comment: @Enijar: It is not doing the same thing. `\b` is context dependent while the `(?<!\w)` and `(?!\w)` always mean one thing: no word char before (1) and no word char after (2).

Answer (score 0):

One important note: in PHP, `\w` may be Unicode aware if you use `/u` modifier, but since you are not using that Unicode mode, the following should work the same way.

JS regex does *not* support *lookbehinds* at all. You need to convert your lookbehind to a *capturing group* containing two alternatives: either the start of string or a non-word char.

So, your constructor will look like

```
new RegExp('(^|\\W)(' + search.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&') + ')(?!\\w)', 'g')
```

Here is a regex demo:

```js
var search = '.search.';
var rx = new RegExp('(^|\\W)(' + search.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&') + ')(?!\\w)', 'g');
var s = ".search. .search.";
while ((m=rx.exec(s))!==null) {
  if (m[1]) {
     console.log(m.index+1, rx.lastIndex);
   } else { 
     console.log(m.index, rx.lastIndex);
   }
}
```

```css
span.highlight {
  color: #FF0000;
 }
```

The `(^|\\W)` will match and capture the start of string or a non-word char into Group 1 (referenced with `$1` backreference from the replacement pattern) and the search word is escaped with `.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&')` (just in case there are special chars like `.`, `(`, etc.). The search word is captured into Group 2.

The lookaheads are supported the same way as in PHP, so you may use `(?!\\w)` as in the original regex.

The `m.index` will fetch the match start position, thus, we need to check if Group 1 is not empty. If it is not, it match a non-word symbol, so we need t increment it before using. Else, just use plain `m.index`. The end position is the `RegExp.lastIndex` property value.

Comment: I have modified the question. Apologising for the late changes. I want to search for the word and want to get it's starting index and ending index.